# WPF ContextMenu text alignment

Tags: c#, wpf, alignment, contextmenu

I am building a context menu for a WPF application and if I have text and then I add an image, the text is always aligned at the top of the menu item and I can't figure out how to align it to the center.

I have tried the `VerticalAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` properties but they dont help.. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on what kind of panel you are using to host the text and the image. I tried with a `StackPanel` and once I added `VerticalAlignment="Center"`, the text was aligned correctly. Please provide some more information if it still doesn't work out for you.

```
<Button Content="Right-click me">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem>
                <MenuItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">Menu item 1</TextBlock>
                        <Image Source="image.png" Height="50" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </MenuItem.Header>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I get stuck like this, I fire up Snoop (https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf) and use it to figure out which control is aligned incorrectly.